# Python3: How does del List[List.index('item')] work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, del

```
myList = ['hi', 'hello', 'wassup', 'hey']
del myList[myList.index('hi')]
```

I do not understand how the second line worked.

Comment: What part of the second line do you not understand exactly. Is it `myList.index(...)` or `del myList[...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first using the `index` method, it tries to find the index of the first occurrence of "hi" in `myList` (which is 0). Then it will remove the 0 index from the list using `del`. You can have better understanding using below snippet.

```py
myList = ['hi', 'hello', 'wassup', 'hey']
hi_index = myList.index('hi')    # -> 0
del myList[hi_index]
```

So the above snippet will remove the first occurrence of "hi" from the `myList` and the result must be `['hello', 'wassup', 'hey']`.

I should also point out that if the item is not available in the list, `index` will be raise an `ValueError` exception. So to use `index` you must be sure about the item existence.

Comment: But how does ```del myList[myList.index[0])``` work?

Comment: @Ayush It doesn't. `myList.index[0]` can't and does not work. That aside, what bit you wondering about *exactly*: `myList.index(...)`, `myList[...]`, `del ...` or `del myList[...]`?

Comment: @Ayush `myList.index[0]` is different from `myList[0]`. Actually `myList.index(x)` will be find the index of 'x' element in `myList` and `myList[0]` points to first element of `myList`.